# Mysql sum of row values depending of the other same field

Tags: android, mysql, json, phpmyadmin

I need to Sum of Cash and Credit of each company with Corresponding date

```
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+----------
| ID        |  SaleDate  | Cash          | Credit |company  |
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+----------
|         1 | Nov-12-2016| 100           |     150|company 1|
|         2 | Nov-12-2016| 200           |     100|Company 1|
|         3 | Nov-13-2016| 150           |     200|Company 2|
|         4 | Nov-13-2016| 250           |     250|Company 2|
|         5 | Nov-14-2016| 80            |      50|Company 3|
|         6 | Nov-14-2016| 500           |     600|Company 3|
|           | Nov-15-2016| 300           |     300|Company 4|
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+---------+
```

Desired OutPut is

```
+------------+---------------+--------+----------
|  SaleDate  | Cash          | Credit |company  |
+------------+---------------+--------+----------
| Nov-12-2016| 300           |     250|company 1|
| Nov-13-2016| 400           |     450|Company 2|
| Nov-14-2016| 580           |     650|Company 3|
| Nov-15-2016| 300           |     300|Company 4|
+-----------+------------+---------------+------+
```

i don' know how to do this please help me to find a solution thanks in advance...

Comment: This is really a basic question. There are many question in SO with the same scenario. Try proper research before asking this repeated questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  SaleDate,sum(Cash)Cash,sum(Credit)Credit,company   
from tbl_name group by  
SaleDate,company
```

Comment: its working perfectly thank you so much....

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
 SELECT SUM(cash) AS Total_cash,SUM(Credit) AS Total_credit,*
 FROM `table_name` 
 GROUP BY SaleDate
```